# GWT - Debugging in Eclipse without showing the library code

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, gwt

I'm trying to use the Eclipse debugger, setting breakpoints in my code, to see what lines are being called. The problem is that the debugger also shows the lines of code called inside GWT jars (probably because the code can be seen). 
Is there a way to change the setting so that lines of code that are outside my project are not shown when they are called ?

Comment: This may help: http://eclipseone.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/skip-over-certain-classes-when-using-step-into-in-eclipses-debugger/

Answer (score 0):

Use  one of the f5, f6, or f7 keys. I don't remember which one is you wanted. It's hint was step out or something on the toolbar.